# Need help streaming large data in C# client (HttpWebRequest) when server is in streamed mode

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming

i'm scratching my head, - i have problems uploading large data into a WCF server.
i saw a post that suggests to use async programming because it ignores the HTTPWebRequest timeouts.
i saw several problems:

1. when doing "GetRequestStream / GetRequestStreamAsync" nothing happens at the server side, the upload method is not called.
2. When performing Write / WriteAsync into the stream, nothing happens at the server side, the upload method is not called
3. When doing "GetResponse / GetResponseAsync" - only then, the upload method starts. if i **close** the client application, the server **still uploads the file** - meaning, the streamed data is written to somewhere not inside the client process.

i tried with flush / without flush / async / sync - nothing solves the problem.

What am i doing wrong? how to stream large data properly into the server from C#?
The server is RESTful wcf, and is configured to allow streaming of big data.

The async code is something like this:

```
               HttpWebRequest request = RESTUtils.InitializeRequest(...);
               request.SendChunked = true
               request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;


               using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
               {
                  // We will write the stream to the request
                  byte[] buffer = new byte[UPLOAD_FILE_BUFFER_SIZE];
                  int read = await i_RequestStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                  while (read > 0)
                  {
                     await requestStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read, m_SessionCancellationToken); // nothing happens at server
                     await requestStream.FlushAsync();
                     m_SessionCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                     read = await i_RequestStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                  }             
               }

               using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync()) // ONLY here the REST method starts
               {
                  using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                  {
                     actualResult = RESTUtils.StreamReadToEnd(responseStream);
                  }
               }
```

== Update == 
even weirder thing happens - i've set a breakpoint right after the write, and waited something like 5 minutes, only then, the server got the request (even though the client is in break-point.
the server did not wait for the client to finish sending the data (closing the stream) - it just read like several KB from the file, and then the closed the file - causing a partial file in the server.
i have no idea what i'm doing wrong

Comment: try to send the data chunk by chunk instead of sending the entire file. This suite only if you have large file.

Comment: @Chandru this is what i do.. see the Write loop.
it's not working, the server doesn't pop up anything until the request stream is closed...

Comment: @ArielB But you said upload only starts when GetResponse/GetResponseAsync got called? So when exactly the service side can get data? When client call stream.Close or when client side call GetResponse/GetResponseAsync ?

Comment: @codewarrior at the GetResponse. then the server service starts. so it caches the data somewhere. which is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending large data to a WCF service, you'll need to increase the **maxRecievedMessageSize** in its binding in your app/web config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRandomService" 
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
       </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
       <endpoint address="http://localhost:4568/Random" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRandomService" 
          contract="BusinessServiceAPI.IRandomService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IRandomService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I've already done it, my issue is not that i cant send large files, the issue is that the server doesn't start until the request stream is closed. i have no idea where the stream is written to.